# flowplayer - Stop video after X seconds and execute javascript code

Tags: flowplayer

I need some help with flowplayer…
I want create player like this: moviechannel.pl/player/
So, i want like this: Someone go to page, click on the play button and video start and after X seconds stop and execute javascript code. how create something like this??

Answer (score 2):

You can use cue points or content plugin in flowplayer, below is link:

http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/events/cuepoints.html
http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/flash/content.html

but the function which is called on that cuepoint, you need to pause the video and after completion of javascript you need to resume your video
 Use `$f().pause();` to pause 
and `$f().resume();` to resume video in your function